# Where to view app memory usage in iPod Touch?

Tags: ios, applications, ipod-touch, memory

On my iPod Touch I cannot find where to view app static memory usage (not RAM).

Googled articles point to `Settings -> General -> Usage`. But Usage is not an option within the General section - it is not appearing. I'm using latest version of iOS.

Where should I go to view the installed app static memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

As reported in this webpage: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656.

You can go to Settings to see how much storage you've used by following: `Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage`.

In there you'll see a list of your apps, and how much storage each one uses. Tap an app for more detailed information about its usage.